# Is there an algorithm to uniformly sample (order) lattices without generating all of them?

Tags: sampling, algorithms

I'm planning out a project that involves [lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) in the [order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory) sense of "lattice". I am assuming the number of vertices is known ahead of time.

Unfortunately I have only found resources related to [lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_model_(physics)) in a crystal or (undirected) graph embedding sense.

As such it would not be difficult to sample uniformly from Bernoulli variables indicating whether an edge exists and then reject those that do not match the structure of a lattice. This seems inefficient, and possibly non-uniform. Even more non-uniform but possibly more efficient would be to incrementally sample edges to build out the lattice.

I was reading in [Deleu *et al.* 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.13903) that some improvements have been made in sampling directed acyclic graphs due to a general interest in structural learning. But this only gets as far as directed acyclic graphs in its current state. Maybe with considerably more work I could figure out how their method works and adapt it to lattices, but I am hoping something already exists for my use case.

For a really small number of vertices I could generate all of them and explicitly assign probabilities to them. While lattices are a subset of partial orders, [OEIS A001035](https://oeis.org/A001035) is suggestive that this approach will fail for even modest problems. Rather, I need something that *generates* the lattice as part of the sampling.

Are there algorithms for uniformly-sampling lattices given that the number of vertices is known?

Comment: It seems like this paper claims to do it: https://www.emis.de/journals/MB/125.2/mb125_2_1.pdf (Jezek et al, "Random, Posets, Lattices and Lattice Terms", Math. Bohemica 125, 2000).

Comment: It also seems to have been implemented in sage: https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/20495